# Select active and inactive used in last 7 days MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `login_history` in which `login_time` and `logout_time` against a `user_id` is being stored. I am interested in getting the list of `user_ids` who are **active** in the last 7 days and who are **inactive** using another query.

I am using this query `select user_id from login_history where login_time <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY` it showing be `user_id 1,2` in output. How could I get the `active` and `inactive` users id in on the basis of the last 7 days?

[image: login_history_table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test `MAX(login_time)` to see if they've been active recently.

This returns the inactive users.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM login_history
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(login_time) <= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

To get the active users, you can simply use `DISTINCT` after filtering for recent login times.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM login_history
WHERE login_time > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Comment: Sir your answer results in `user_id 2` . THe user 2 is **inactive**.

Comment: That's correct, the query returns the inactive users.